# Python base 64 para imagem

Tags: mysql, python

Pessoal estou pegando 1 foto do banco de dados porem está vindo como base 64 , nisso preciso que ela vire imagem novamente para poder localizar na tela , como transformo a base 64 em bites novamente?
Tentei assim porem da 1 erro

```
agua = str(dataBase.read_fotos("foto", "agua", "1"))
agua = agua[4:]
agua = agua[:-4]
img_agua = base64.b64decode(agua)
rod = str(dataBase.read_fotos("foto", "vara", "1"))
rod = rod[4:]
rod = rod[:-4]
img_rod = base64.b64decode(rod)

# -------------------------------encontrar posições--------------------
water_position = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img_agua)
rod_position = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img_rod)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'mode'
```

Answer (score 1):

A biblioteca PIL deve resolver:

```
import PIL.Image as Image

image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(bytes))
```

Onde `bytes` é a variável que possui os bytes da imagem.

Espero que ajude

Comment: certo, porem essa variável com os bytes, está codificada em base 64, oque eu precisava era mudar para bytes, você acha que a pil funcionaria para o meu caso ?

Comment: Não seria o caso de usar `bytearray(sua_variavel_base_64)` ?

Comment: tentei desta forma ele deu o seguinte erro

Comment: img_agua = bytearray(agua)
TypeError: string argument without an encoding

Comment: Tente `bytes(sua_variavel, encoding='utf8')`. Caso não funcione, coloque o conteúgo de sua variável em um gist e atualize seu post.